# what this shell script will do?

Tags: shell, unix

```
claProductVersion=`head -l ${amSqlCre}` 
claProductVersion=`expr "${claProductVersion}" : 'Create Table \([^ ]*\) ('`
```

1. Why we are using "**:**" here ?
2. What ([^ ]*) is doing ?
3. What does head -l doing ? As I did not find any "**l**" option in head man pages.

Comment: Is that a `1` instead of `l` ?

Comment: that would be 1 (One) not l and it extracts the first line of the given file.

Comment: the extracted line which head gives is "Create Table ne_GLOBAL (", what they are doing in second line

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1 `man expr` will tell you `STRING : REGEXP` and this means `anchored pattern match of REGEXP in STRING`

2 The regexp `\([^ ]*\)` will match strings like `xxx`. `[^ ]` means any character except whitespace. And `*` means repeat any times including zero.  The `\(` and `\)` means showing the string matched. Without them, the result will the position the regexp matched.

3 Still I guess there's something wrong. `l` doesn't make sense here. It should be a `1`.

Comment: yes it is one(1), I was confused, thx

Comment: what will be present in 'claProductVersion' in 2nd line

Comment: @user1160090 The first line code will assign the first line text in amSqlCre to `calProductVersion`. And have a try like `expr "Create Table ne_GLOBAL (" : 'Create Table \([^ ]*\) ('` in a shell. That will help you know what happens.

Comment: yes I got the answer, it will contain ne_GLOBAL